# How do I set Zsh autocompletion rules for second argument (of function) to an existing command's rules?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, git

I have [a custom Zsh function `g`](https://github.com/prelang/g):

```
function g() {
  # Handle arguments [...]
}
```

Within it, I handle short arguments that execute Git commands.  For example:

```
g ls # Executes git ls-files ...
g g  # Executes git grep ...
```

I need to be able to set the autocompletion rules to Git's rules for the short arguments but I am unsure of how to do this.

For example, I need `g ls <TAB>` to tab-complete the rules for `git ls-files <TAB>` which would give me the arguments for `git ls-files`:

```
$ g ls --<TAB>
--abbrev                 -- set minimum SHA1 display-length
--cached                 -- show cached files in output
--deleted                -- show deleted files in output
# Etc...
```

This is not simply setting `g` to autocomplete for `git` since I'm mapping my custom short commands to the Git commands.

Comment: If your function only maps shorter names to git subcommands you can also use the git alias system for this. Read about it in the mapage: `man git-config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git` which had some tips for aliases like this and ended up defining these functions for the aliases:

```
_git-ls () {
  # Just return the _git-ls-files autocomplete function
  _git-ls-files
}
```

Then, I did a straight `compdef g=git`.  The autocomplete system will see that you are running, for example, `g ls` and use the `_git-ls` autocomplete function.

Thanks to user67060 for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something very similar so this is roughly what should solve your problem.

```
_g () {
    case "${words[2]}" in
      ls) words[1,2]=(git ls-files);;
      g) words[1,2]=(git grep);;
      *) return 1;;
    esac

    _git # Delegate to completion
}
compdef _g g
```

One thing to note is that if you change the number of arguments you will need to adjust the `$CURRENT` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
_tg () {
    local _ret=1
    local cur cword prev

    cur=${words[CURRENT]}
    prev=${words[CURRENT-1]}
    cmd=${words[2]}
    let cword=CURRENT-1

    case "$cmd" in
    ls)
        emulate ksh -c _git_ls_files
        ;;
    g)
        emulate ksh -c _git_grep
        ;;
    esac

    let _ret && _default && _ret=0
    return _ret
}

compdef _tg tg
```

However, this is using Git's completion, not zsh's completion:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going a different route since I didn't know where to find the Git completion rules and was getting errors.  See my answer.