# How to combine zsh autocomplete for wrapper function arguments and existing command

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I work mostly in gvim and many terminals.  Originally, I preferred to open all my files in a single vim instance.  To that end I used an alias to open files from my terminals in the current 'vim server'.

```
alias rv="gvim --remote-silent"
```

But having many files from multiple projects open in a single vim instance impacts my productivity, so I'm upgrading my alias to a function.

```
# main function
rv() {
    local args options server

    options=$(getopt -o hils:t: -l "help,info,list,set:,target:" -- "$@")

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Failed to parse options."
        return 1
    fi

    # a little magic, necessary when using getopt
    eval set -- "$options"

    # go through the options with a case and use shift to analyze one option at a time.
    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            -h|--help)
                echo "Usage: $0 [-hil] [--help] [--info] [--list]";
                echo "       $0 {-s | --set} <name> [<file1 file2...>]";
                echo "       $0 {-t | --target} <name>] <file1 file2...>";
                return 0;;
            -i|--info)
                gvim_show_info;
                return 0;;
            -l|--list)
                gvim_list_servers;
                return 0;;
            -s|--set)
                gvim_set_server_name ${2:u};
                shift 2;;
            -t|--target)
                server="$2";
                shift 2;;
            --)
                shift;
                break;;
        esac
    done

    if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
        # if no files specified...
        if [[ -n "$server" ]]; then
            # throw error if --target option was specified.
            echo "Error!  --target requires one or more filenames."
            return 1;
        fi
    else
        # if files were specified...
        if [[ -n "$server" ]]; then
            # if --target was specified
            gvim_run_remote $server "$@"
        else
            gvim_run_remote $(gvim_get_default_server) "$@"
        fi
    fi

    return 0;
}
```

Now this new `rv` has it's own options.  I can use it to:

- list available vim servers (-l --list)
- set the default vim server for the current shell (-s --set)
- show the default vim server (-i --info)
- open files in a specific vim server (-t --target)
- open files in default vim server: `rv files...`

However, since I'm using a function for `rv` instead of an alias, I lose the zsh completion I previously enjoyed.  I've read up on creating a completion function, `_rv`, that will show `rv`'s options, but I want to combine my completion options with the existing vim completion options.  I know there may be some conflicts with `rv`'s `-s` and `vim`'s `-s`, but I figure I can handle that elegantly with the `--` separator.

**TLDR;** So, how do I create a completion script that combines the `_arguments` options for both `_rv` and `_vim`?  I prefer to reuse `_vim` if possible instead of copy-pasting it's arguments list into `_rv`.

Here's my `_rv`.  *Updated 2014/6/10 16:10*

```
#compdef rv

_rv() {
    typeset -A opt_args
    local alternatives

    alternatives=(
        'args:rv options:_rv_options'
        'files:file:_vim_files'
    )

    _alternative $alternatives && return 0

    return 1
}

_rv_options() {
    local arguments

    arguments=(
        '(-i -l -s -t --info --list --set --target)'{-h,--help}'[Print usage info.]'
        '(-h -l -s -t --help --list --set --target)'{-i,--info}'[Print default vim server. As stored in $GVIM_SERVER.]'
        '(-i -h -s -t --info --help --set --target)'{-l,--list}'[Print list of existing vim servers.]'
        '(-i -h -l -t --info --help --list --target)'{-s,--set}'[Set default vim server for the current shell.]:vim servers:_rv_vim_servers'
        '(-i -h -l -s --info --help --list --set)'{-t,--target}'[Open files in a particular vim server.]:vim servers:_rv_vim_servers'
        )

    _arguments -s -C $arguments && return 0

    return 1
}

_rv_vim_servers() {
    local -a servers
    servers=( ${(f)"$(_call_program servers vim --serverlist 2>/dev/null)"} )
    _wanted servers expl server compadd -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' -a servers && return
}

# invoke the completion command during autoload
_rv "$@"
```

**Current Behavior**

Currently `_rv` completion will is usable, but not ideal.

- When I type `rv <TAB>`, I do not see the vim options.  Only rv options and file paths are displayed.  `_vim` is completing file paths for me, so hooray to that!
- When I type `rv -s <TAB>`, I see the list of vim servers, but also the file paths are displayed.  A file is not permitted at this point in the command, and should not appear in the autocomplete.

**Expected Behavior**

- When I type `rv <TAB>`, I expect to see: 1) rv options, 2) vim options, 3) file path list
- When I type `rv -s <TAB>`, I expect to see: 1) vim server names (as provided by `_rv_vim_servers`.
- When I type `rv /valid/file/path/<TAB>`, I expect to only see a file path list.  Since `_vim` already has this capability, I would prefer to rely on it.

Comment: This http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128199/how-do-i-set-zsh-autocompletion-rules-for-second-argument-of-function-to-an-ex could be useful.

Comment: `compdef` has a `-n` option which says it "prevents any completions already defined for the command or context from being overwritten". So, have you tried `compdef _vim rv` followed by `compdev -n _rv rv` ?

Comment: 28 upvotes and no answer... and it's a question about zsh... I'll try to invoke @StéphaneChazelas  for you ^^ (I try not to abuse this, but it's fun. Please Stephane, tell me if I should not do this... and I'll delete this and never do it again) ... If someone here may know the answer, it should be him

Comment: @OlivierDulac I think you only get notifications if you have already posted in the thread. (Duplicate names are allowed, so this makes sense.) You could possibly find him in chat though.

Comment: Could it be possible to source the original `_vim`  file, but before doing so overwrite the `_arguments` function with a custom local function? By doing so you would get the arguments from `_vim`. Maybe with a separate zsh process.

Comment: Does my post below answer your question? If so, please Accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can [monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the `_arguments` function to extend the `_vim` completer:

```bsh
#compdef rv

_rv_vim_servers() {
    local expl
    _wanted servers expl server \
        compadd -- ${(f)"$( _call_program servers vim --serverlist 2>/dev/null )"}
}

_rv() {
  autoload +X -Uz _arguments             # Load the function body.
  functions -c _arguments _rv_arguments  # Make a copy.

  # Replace the original function.
  _arguments() {
    # Call the original function with additional completions.
    _rv_arguments "$@" \
        '(-i -l -s -t --info --list --set --target)'{-h,--help}'[print usage info]' \
        '(-h -l -s -t --help --list --set --target)'{-i,--info}'[print default vim server as stored in $GVIM_SERVER]' \
        '(-i -h -s -t --info --help --set --target)'{-l,--list}'[print list of existing vim servers]' \
        '(-i -h -l -t --info --help --list --target)'{-s,--set}'[set default vim server for the current shell]:vim servers:_rv_vim_servers' \
        '(-i -h -l -s --info --help --list --set)'{-t,--target}'[open files in a particular vim server]:vim servers:_rv_vim_servers'
  }

  {
    _vim "$@"
  } always {
    functions -c _rv_arguments _arguments  # Restore the original.
    unfunction _rv_arguments               # Discard our copy.
  }
}

_rv "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git which had some tips for aliases like this and ended up defining these functions for the aliases:

```
_git-ls () {
  # Just return the _git-ls-files autocomplete function
  _git-ls-files
}
```

Then, do a straight compdef g=git. The autocomplete system will see that you are running, for example, g ls and use the _git-ls autocomplete function.

As found [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128358/210788)

Comment: thanks, but not quite.  your solution assumes I only want the auto-complete from `_git-ls-files`.  This question has a `git-ls` (to stick with your convention) with its own options, and some of those options overlap with `git-ls-files`.  Instead of writing autocomplete for all options of `git-ls`, how do I write an autocomplete that takes the autocomplete from `_git-ls-files` (which covers say 90%), and combines them with the autocomplete of the remaining (say 10%) options?